# Hibernate @OneToMany relation cascade option not working

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I design simple 1:N schema , Account(1):AccountProfileImage(N).

Below codes are entity codes.

```java
// Account.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Account {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="account",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final List<AccountProfileImage> profileImages= new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Builder
    public Account(String email,String firstName,String lastName,String password){
        this.email=email;
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.password=password;
    }
}

// AccountProfileImage.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "account_profile_image")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AccountProfileImage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageURL;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Builder
    public AccountProfileImage (Account account,String imageURL){
        this.account=account;
        // this.account.addProfileImage(this);
        this.imageURL=imageURL;
    }
}
```

and this is test code for AccountProfileRepository code.

```java
@Test
    @Rollback(value = false)
    public void saveAccountProfileImageTest() throws Exception {
        // given
        Account account = Account.builder()
                .email("user@email.com")
                .firstName("user")
                .lastName("user")
                .password("1234")
                .build();


        AccountProfileImage profileImage = AccountProfileImage.builder()
                .account(account)
                .imageURL("pathToURI")
                .build();


        AccountProfileImage profileImage2 = AccountProfileImage.builder()
                .account(account)
                .imageURL("pathToURI2")
                .build();

        accountRepository.save(account);

        

        // when
        List<AccountProfileImage> images = profileImageRepository.findAllByAccount_IdOrderByCreatedAtDesc(1L);
        // then
        // this assertion fail
        assertThat(images.size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
```

What i want to expect find by List of images whose size is 2 because I add `CscadeType.ALL` in `Account` entity class and when creating `AccountProfileImage` object, I set account member variable in `AccountProfileImage` object.

> this.account=account;

Did I something wrong?

---

I add below method in Account entity and 2 lines at test code, then it works fine. Do i have to do this everytime? Is there exist another better approach or best practice?

```java
// Account Entity
public void addProfileImages(AccountProfileImage image){
        this.profileImages.add(image);
    }

// test code
account.addProfileImages(profileImage);
account.addProfileImages(profileImage2);

accountRepository.save(account);

// when
List<AccountProfileImage> images = profileImageRepository.findAllByAccount_IdOrderByCreatedAtDesc(1L);

// then
// this assertion pass
assertThat(images.size()).isEqualTo(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bi-directional relationships, you have to define the association on both ends of the relationship. To avoid any issues, you can update the helper `addProfileImage(..)` method to add the `AccountProfileImage` to the list and set `account` property of the image to the current account. This is the best practice as this way, the helper method will set up the association across both ends of the bi-directional relationship.

E.g.

```
public void addProfileImages(AccountProfileImage image){
    this.profileImages.add(image); // Add image to profileImages
    image.setAccount(this); // Set account property to the current account
}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
    @Rollback(value = false)
    public void saveAccountProfileImageTest() throws Exception {
        // given
        Account account = Account.builder()
                .email("user@email.com")
                .firstName("user")
                .lastName("user")
                .password("1234")
                .build();


        AccountProfileImage profileImage = AccountProfileImage.builder()
                .imageURL("pathToURI")
                .build();


        AccountProfileImage profileImage2 = AccountProfileImage.builder()
                .imageURL("pathToURI2")
                .build();

        // Setup association
        account.addProfileImage(profileImage);
        account.addProfileImage(profileImage2);

        accountRepository.save(account);

        

        // when
        List<AccountProfileImage> images = profileImageRepository.findAllByAccount_IdOrderByCreatedAtDesc(1L);
        // then
        // this assertion fail
        assertThat(images.size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rehman! I have one additional question. From what I learned from class about entity, adding a setter method in entity is not a good idea. So I choose make association between  AccountProfileImage and account using builder when entity is created. Could you tell your opinion about this?

Comment: I think it's better to have setters only for those fields that your app uses, so I think what you did is nice.